# Custom Button on Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I added custom button on my `view.html.php` file of VIEW of my component  as :

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('addtrack', 'addtrack.png', 'addtrack_f2.png','Add Track', false);
JToolBarHelper::custom('edittrack', 'edittrack.png', 'edittrack_f2.png','Edit Track', false);

JToolBarHelper::custom('updatetrack', 'updatetrack.png', 'updatetrack_f2.png','Save Track', false);
```

but i dont know from where i can use this buttons, i mean i want to open my respective pages which i created under the same view.

```
"track_addtrack.php"
```

or i can do some part of work using this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons will execute a task so you have to implement it in your controller.

so in /controllers/{view_name}.php you need to add functions that match your custom names given in the buttons.

Example

```
class YourcomponentControllerYourview extends JController {

    public function addtrack() {

        //Put code you want to execute here 
        //You could forexample require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE.'/views/yourview/track_addtrack.php');

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... actually i was adding the function on com_name/controllers.php
thanks alot...